# Can we make changes to the django packages

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Is it okay to make changes to the django packages?
For instance in my project I have a folder lib/python2.7/site-packages/reversion/
And in here I want to add one method inside of models.py
Is this correct?

Initially I wanted to edit django's admin history page. In some models history change messages are shown in unicode format, but I need it to be string readable. In models.py I used eval function to transfer unicode to python list.

Answer (score 2):

No, this is not a good practice.
In general there is other way to edit the default feature (inheritance, write your own page, etc...).
This is because if you modify the django package this becomes difficult to maintain and update.
But if it is a small project you can try to edit django package.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. One more question: Do you know, how to add additional custom method to the default models.py in site packages/reversion/?

Comment: What do you want to do? And please be more specific in where is this models.py (I do not find it)

Comment: When you create a django project, inside of the project folder there is a folder /lib/python2.7/site-package/reversion/ and here is the model.py is located. I added here new method which converts unicode to python list

Comment: I don't have that package installed. The right way to do this is a [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters)